# Get everything that is a number (digit) after a= but stop when numbers stop

Tags: python, python-2.7

The string can be..

```
a=0123
```

or it can be

```
a=0123;y=83920şs
```

the goal is to simply get what is after 'a=' or even after '1=' if it looks like this..

```
1=0123;y=83920şs
```

but it must stop when numbers stop.. in other words in this example.. the output should be..

```
0123
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Regex? Walking through the string manually?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I do not even know anything about regex.

Comment: i think i tried split..   `b = b.split('1=')
  b = b[1]` i ended up with strange stuff..

Comment: Researching basic regular expressions would be a fantastic place to start.

Comment: OP have a look at this [regex tutorial](http://regexone.com). Regex is the most appropriate tool for this, and well worth learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) from python Regular expression module :

```
>>>import re
>>> s='a=0123;y=83920\xc5\x9fs'
>>> m=re.search(r'(?<=a=|1=)[\d]+',s)
>>> print m.group(0)
0123
```

if you have `1=` in you r string too ! you can use `re.findall()` method !

```
>>> s="a=0123;y=83920şs;1=346174"
>>> m=re.findall(r'(?<=a=|1=)[\d]+',s)
>>> m
['0123', '346174']
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a digit after the equals sign.

```
from itertools import  takewhile

s ="a=0123;y=83920şs"

print "".join(takewhile(lambda x:  x.isdigit(),s.split("=")[1]))
0123
```

`s.split("=")[1]` gets the element after the `=` sign, `takewhile(lambda x:  x.isdigit())` will get all the digits  stopping when we meet a non digit.

If there are no digits after the `;` you can use `isdigit`

```
 "".join([x for x in s.split("=")[1] if x.isdigit()])
```

The will work on any string in the same format:

```
s1 ="1=0123;y=83920şs"
print "".join([x for x in s1.split("=")[1] if x.isdigit()])
print "".join(takewhile(lambda x:  x.isdigit(),s1.split("=")[1]))
0123
0123
```